# Watch or evaluate expressions while debugging in Anypoint Studio (Mule ESB)

Tags: debugging, mule, anypoint-studio

How can I watch or evaluate expressions while debugging Mule flow in Anypoint Studio. I need something similar to Eclipse Debug Watch window where I can evaluate an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run the Mule app in Debug Mode, then the Studio will navigate you to Debug Perspective. In case you are not in that perspective, then click menu:

- Window >> Perspective >> Open Perspective
- Choose: Mule Debug
- If it is not listed, then choose Other... and select Mule Debug on the new displayed window

At the top right of this perspective, make sure to open tab: Mule Expression Watches. There is a **+** button to add new mule expression to watch.

[image]

In case there is no certain tab, then click menu:

- Window >> Show View >> Mule Expression Watches
- If it is not listed, then choose Other... and type Mule Expression Watches on the new displayed window

[image]